# GUI J UNIT Testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, gui-testing

For a class I have to replicate a rather intricate bug from an open source project. The project has tens of thousands of lines of code, and I have never really tested a GUI before. I am having a difficult time finding where all of the constructors and methods are called throughout the project.

I'm using the Eclipse IDE. The bug is replicated through a series of interactions with different parts of the GUI. I have looked online through different open source GUI projects, however it seems that most of these projects just generate scripts to repeat the clicks that I make.

What is the simplest way to find all of the method call sites to replicate the bug using JUNIT? Is there a simple way I can follow method calls in the Eclipse debugger to see what is called when a button is clicked?

Is there an open source GUI testing project that will follow my clicks and create a resulting JUNIT test that can be run?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source tool called [Swing Explorer](http://www.swingexplorer.com/) which can help you to identify the  Swing GUI component instance that is buggy in runtime. Then it should be easy to find it in the source code.

Once you find the component in the source code you can ask IDE to show to the call hierarchy (Ctrl+Alt+H).

For automating UI testing I'd recommend to take a look at [Swing FEST](https://code.google.com/p/fest/) (it doesn't support test code generation, though) and Google's [WindowTester Pro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wintester/html/index).

Comment: Another library for automated Swing GUI testing is Jemmy (integrates well with JUnit)